# How to align material icon within a FlatButton using FlexBox?

Tags: flexbox, material-ui

I'm trying to align a Google material icon within material-ui FlatButton using FlexBox.
I've tried several permutations, but always with the same outcome -- the icon sits at the very bottom of the button. I'm not sure if this is a material-ui specific problem. How can I achieve alignment properly?

```
  <FlatButton
    style = {buttonStyle}
    onClick = {
      onIncrementClick
    }
    icon={<i style= {{display:'flex', alignItems:'center', verticalAlign: 'center'}} className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>}
    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the docs here - http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button?

They have examples of icons in flat buttons on the left and the right. Here's the code to have the icon on the right:

```
<FlatButton
  label="Label before"
  labelPosition="before"
  primary={true}
  style={styles.button}
  icon={<ActionAndroid />}
/>
```

Comment: Yup I've seen that. I was hoping for more fine grained though. Vertically centered was what I was trying to go for. In any case I'll probably go with IconButton instead since it looks more materialy